# Term or phrase for something that changes one's life (for the better) dramatically

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am searching for a phrase to describe a physical object that brought tremendous and positive **changes** to one's life.

> Behind this flawed creation of technology, however, was hiding *an epochal momentum of my life*.

I did some research and came up with the phrase *epochal momentum*, but I could not coherently connect it to my life. Also, I want to contrast **this flawed creation of technology** to something that is stylistically fit and literarily sound.

Comment: Game-changer, life-saver.

Comment: @Hot Licks thank you for your suggestion, but I want to use more formal or literarily allusive word instead of _game-changer_.

Answer (score 1):

***[Boon](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boon)***

> Something that is very helpful and improves the quality of life.

--Cambridge Dictionary

You could modify it with a word such as tremendous, or major to stress the *tremendous* and *dramatic* impact of the boon.

*Behind this flawed creation of technology, however, was hiding an epochal momentum of my life.*

Your sentence is a little awkward (epochal momentum, aside), I would rewrite like so:

> Behind this flawed creation of technology, however, was what was to
>   become a major boon for my life.

Comment: Uh… isn't using *epochal* for an individual life at best extremely grandiose?

Doesn't *momentum* belong purely to physics?

Doesn't a *boon* apply to a person, not to his life?

Something like *pivotal moment* might go some way to correcting *epochal momentum* but it won’t do the job by itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Philosopher's stone* gets you closer at least.

Answer (score 0):

More the experience of something than the thing itself,  but *epiphany* comes close, I think. For example, the firm [Epihany A.G.](https://www.epiphany.li/) states on its website:

*An experience of sudden enlightenment, a positive feeling, a scientific or economic breakthrough which allows a problem or situation to be understood from a deeper or new perspective. This is an epiphany*.